# circuit test is performed on low voltage side ,and reading are given of high voltage side

Tags: circuit-analysis, transformer

There is a question in vk mehta in which open circuit test is performed on low voltage side ,and reading are given. of high voltage side and magnetizing branch ,excitation branch current is  asked.how is this possible?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the ElectricalEngineering.SE. You question is unclear: without any schematic it would be difficult to say and explain why the statement is right/wrong. Please provide context and information, I you want to help other members help you with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be interpreting the question incorrectly. An open circuit test is not performed on the side that is open. One side is open and the other side is energized, Measurements are done on the energized side and the magnetizing branch is assumed to be on that side.